# Hibernate Error Message: IntegratorServiceImpl

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat8

I am currently trying to use Hibernate ORM in one of my projects. And when I try to initiate a ServiceRegistry object i get an error message which I cannot solve, even though I've been looking at several tutorials and I seem to get the same error every time.

I am running Hibernate with Tomcat and Jersey.

This is the class that initiates Hibernate:

```
import com.example.hibernate.HibernateUtil;
import com.example.hibernate.entities.Users;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import java.util.Date;

public class Spider
{
    public Spider(){

        Users user = new Users();
        user.setUserid(1);
        user.setUsername("Quncage");
        user.setEmail("quncage@example.com");
        Date now = new Date();
        int Time = (int) (now.getTime()/1000);
        user.setRegister_time(Time);
        user.setActive(1);
        user.setBanned(0);
        user.setVacation(0);
        user.setConfimed(1);
        user.setUltra_user(1);

        //Get Session
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        //start transaction
        session.beginTransaction();
        //Save the Model object
        session.save(user);
        //Commit transaction
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Userid="+user.getUserid());
        //terminate session factory, otherwise program won't end
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

This is the HibernateUtil function:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil
{
    //XML based configuration
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            System.out.println("Hibernate Configuration loaded");

            /* Error seems to be triggered here */
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            System.out.println("Hibernate serviceRegistry created");

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

            return sessionFactory;
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if(sessionFactory == null) sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
[2014-06-08 02:29:17,946] Artifact server:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
08-Jun-2014 14:29:18.454 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.addServletWithApplication Registering the Jersey servlet application, named Spider, at the servlet mapping /rest/, with the Application class of the same name.
08-Jun-2014 14:29:18.948 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version.<clinit> HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
08-Jun-2014 14:29:18.956 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.2.Final}
08-Jun-2014 14:29:18.958 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit> HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
08-Jun-2014 14:29:18.960 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
08-Jun-2014 14:29:19.062 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
08-Jun-2014 14:29:19.062 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
08-Jun-2014 14:29:19.107 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Users.hbm.xml
Hibernate Configuration loaded
08-Jun-2014 14:29:19.140 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService;)V
[2014-06-08 02:29:19,171] Artifact server:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2014-06-08 02:29:19,171] Artifact server:war exploded: Deploy took 1,225 milliseconds
```

I cannot figure out why i get this error below. I have been searching around a lot but cannot find anyone who have experienced the same error. I would appreciate any help with this matter!

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService;)V
```

Comment: I saw that I had an old Hibernate (4.2.2) library hiding in my project, which of course interrupted everything.